# ps2pdf does not preserve dimensions

Tags: geometry, crop, dvips, ps2pdf, texify

[image]I am using packages geometry and crop in a .tex file. Then, I convert it to .ps (using dvips) and .pdf (using ps2pdf). The problem is that in the .dvi and .ps files all areas (margins, heights and widths) are ok. However, in the .pdf file they are not. How do I tell ps2pdf to generate a .pdf file with exactly the same dimensions as in the .ps file? I tried different options for ps2pdf but none worked.

```latex
\documentclass [pagesize=false,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,fontsize=10pt,twoside,headings=openright,cleardoublepage=empty,headsepline=off]{scrbook}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    mag=1000,
    paperheight=23.5cm, paperwidth=17.2cm,
    height=19.8cm, width=13.2cm,
    textheight=18.8cm, textwidth=13.2cm,
    headheight=0.5cm, headsep=0.5cm,
    includehead,
    nofoot,
    twoside,
    inner=2.0cm, outer=2.0cm, top=2.0cm, bottom=1.7cm,
    nomarginpar
    }
\usepackage[a4,center,cam,noinfo]{crop}
\begin {document}
\crop
\noindent
nonono nono no nonono nono no nonono nono no nonono nono no nonono nono no nonono nono no nonono nono no nonono nono no \end {document}
```

Comment: no code to try?

Comment: Please post the code what you tried

Comment: There it is, tks.

Comment: looks ok, I get an a4 paper. What do you think is wrong?

Comment: Here's [a picture (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EB43M.png) of what I get. Left is `xdvi`, right is Acrobat. I did `latex marcus && dvips marcus && ps2pdf marcus.ps`

Comment: The crop marks are incorrect in my .pdf file (however correct in the -dvi and .ps files)

Comment: Crop marks are closer in .pdf than in .dvi or .ps

Comment: Hopefully the picture above will help. The print of the .ps shows 23.5cm and 17.2cm between crop marks, as desired. However, the print of the .pdf (converted from the .ps with ps2pdf) shows only 22.8cm and 16.6cm.

Comment: did you disable the "fit to paper" (or however it is called for you) option in the printer driver?

Comment: Where is it? In GSView?

Comment: Solved. The problem was not with the PDF file, it was correct. The problem was with the printing of the PDF file. I changed a parameter in the file printing preferences of Acrobat Reader and now the printed sheet looks fine in the printer as well. Thus, there is no problem with ps2pdf and no special option for it is necessary.